# Using Log4Net and the AdoNetAppender to write an XMLLayout parameter to a DbType XML field

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, log4net, log4net-appender

Pretty straightforward question.

I have a table on a SQL Server Database that has an field with a DbType of XML.

I would like to write to that field using the format of Log4Net's XML layout WITHOUT writing a custom appender; using the in-the-box AdoNetAppender.

Below is my current code, however, when it attempts to log, it will insert a record, but the "Exception" field will be blank.

(I've simplified the code for the purpose of this question; it used to write to many other fields using the pattern layout.  I've confirmed that the Appender does work and that log4net is configured properly, I'm just trying to log to a dbtype of XML using log4net's included XMLLayout.)

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <ConnectionStringName value="CONNECTIONSTRING"/>
  <commandText value="dbo.TestLog_Insert @Exception = @Exception" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Exception"/>
    <dbType value="XML"/>
    <size value="4000"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XMLLayout" value="%exception" />
  </parameter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO"/>
    <acceptOnMatch value="true"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>
```

Comment: What is the error, or question?

Comment: As I said in my question:
"Below is my current code, however, when it attempts to log, it will insert a record, but the "Exception" field will be blank."
In other words, my question is:

"How do I use Log4Net and the AdoNetAppender to write an XMLLayout parameter to a DbType XML field?"